# Laravel 5 : call to "get progress" route postponed to the end of long running process

Tags: php, laravel

My Laravel app needs to do some process (on the backend) which can last many tenths of seconds. This is done in a for loop so I have the ability to know the progress during the long running process. In my minimal test (within my Laravel project) it lasts 10 seconds.

```
public function massAction(Request $request) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

        sleep(1);
        Log::info("Progress in long running task is " .$i );

    }

    $output = array(
        'success' => 'Whatever'
    );

    return response()->json($output);
}
```

The process is triggered by a button in a form. When the user clicks on the button, I want the progress to be shown on the page, but the progress is only shown when the long running process completed. This phenomenon is [well described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903318/multiple-ajax-requests-delay-each-other), and I came there from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530743/displaying-progress-while-waiting-for-controller-in-laravel-4/21533886#21533886) that I tried to apply (create a route that returns the progress).

For now I will let the ajax client code aside. As the "getProgress" route is "get" it can be called manually during the long running task (which last here 10 seconds) :

```
 public function getProgress() {
  $progress = rand(0, 100); // for testing purpose only
  Log::info("Progress is " . $progress);
  return response()->json(array($progress));
 }
```

So as you can see there is no use of PHP SESSION, and both methods are independent. Yet when I submit the form, and then go in another tab and request the url of `getProgress`, its result still comes after the long running task has completed. Here is an excerpt of the Laravel log file :

```
[2020-04-16 06:53:49] local.INFO: Progress in long running task is 0  
[2020-04-16 06:53:50] local.INFO: Progress in long running task is 1  
[2020-04-16 06:53:51] local.INFO: Progress in long running task is 2  
[2020-04-16 06:53:52] local.INFO: Progress in long running task is 3  
[2020-04-16 06:53:53] local.INFO: Progress in long running task is 4  
[2020-04-16 06:53:54] local.INFO: Progress in long running task is 5  
[2020-04-16 06:53:55] local.INFO: Progress in long running task is 6  
[2020-04-16 06:53:56] local.INFO: Progress in long running task is 7  
[2020-04-16 06:53:57] local.INFO: Progress in long running task is 8  
[2020-04-16 06:53:58] local.INFO: Progress in long running task is 9  
[2020-04-16 06:53:58] local.INFO: Progress in getProgress is 5
```

I've read that [PHP SESSION will make the calls being queued](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38335206/6351897) (what I am experiencing indeed). But I am not using it at all and neither does Laravel's `Session`. So what is (or what could be) postponing the call to `getProgress` in my Laravel project ? Or put another way what is preventing `getProgress` to return a result immediately ?

Any help appreciated :-),

**Edit : [Laravel dev server is SINGLE-THREADED](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60393783/6351897)**

I was actually testing this on a dev machine via Laravel `artisan serve` which is single-threaded. No wonder then that I experienced that behaviour.
Testing the same process on a real web server (Apache) removed all the problems!

Comment: Can you show your AJAX

Comment: @lufc see my edit although I doubt it comes from javascript since the direct call to `getProgress` via its route has also to wait until the completion of the long running process.